# angularJs - how to get filtered array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter

I have a mover directive with the following html for the list

```html
<select class="select-list" multiple
                        ng-model="unassigned"
                        name="unAssignedList"
                        data-no-dirty-check
                        ng-options="unassignedItem.descrip for unassignedItem in unassignedItems | orderBy:'descrip' | filter: filterCriteria"></select>
```

So, when I use this directive I can specify my filter-criteria like this

```html
<data-sm:duallist-directive ng-required="false" keep-pristine="true"
                                            unassigned-items-title="'@String.Format(Labels.availableX, Labels.items)'"
                                            unassigned-items="currentItemGroup.unassignedItems"
                                            assigned-items-title="'@String.Format(Labels.assignedX, Labels.items)'"
                                            assigned-items="currentItemGroup.assignedItems"
                                            sortable="false"
                                            filter-criteria="{categoryId:selectedCategoryId}"
                                            selected-item="currentItemGroup.selectedItem">
                </data-sm:duallist-directive>
```

The problem is with the MoveAllLeft (or MoveAllRight) buttons. They have the following code:

```js
$scope.moveRightAll = function() {
                    var unassignedItems = $scope.unassignedItems.slice(0);
                    var smItems = $scope.unassignedItems.slice(0);

                    angular.forEach(smItems, function (value, key) {
                        $scope.assignedItems.push(value);
                        removeItem(unassignedItems, value);
                    });
                    $scope.unassignedItems = unassignedItems;
                    if (!$scope.keepPristine)
                        $scope.form.$setDirty();
                    
                    $scope.assigned = null;
                };
```

The problem is that it works against original unfiltered array. Say, if I have 642 items in total and I filtered them by category to only, say, 5, I only want to move these 5 items when I press my button, not all 642 which I don't even see on the screen.

How can I modify my code to get only items which are filtered? Also, I don't have to enter filter-criteria, so it should work correctly when nothing is entered in the filter-criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem - it turned out to be very easy. I added the following code at the top

```js
var filteredData ;
                    if ($scope.filterCriteria)
                        filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.unassignedItems, $scope.filterCriteria);
                    else
                        filteredData = $scope.unassignedItems;

                    var unassignedItems = filteredData.slice(0);
                    var smItems = filteredData.slice(0);
```

and now only filtered items are moved.